# How to limit the number of consumed messaged in rabbitmq?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq

I'm working with `rabbitmq` with [amqplib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib) in my `node` project.

I use the queue to pass job messages between services.
One of the services consume those message, doing some process and return the result to another queue.

Sometimes the queue holds a **lot** of messages, and the service try to consume them all at once,  hence resulting the process (service) to crash.

How can I limit the number of messages a channel / service can handle?
I thought of a custom solution, holding a global limit, but I'd rather use it as a last resort...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from your question, but it seems you want to limit how your service consumes the messages and not how many messages the queue holds. 
If that understanding is correct, then what you need is `prefetch_count`. More documentation: https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
    var q = 'task_queue';

    ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: true});
    ch.prefetch(1);                // THIS SHOULD SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM
    console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", q);
    ch.consume(q, function(msg) {
      var secs = msg.content.toString().split('.').length - 1;

      console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(" [x] Done");
        ch.ack(msg);
      }, secs * 1000);
    });
  });
});
```

Code source: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-javascript.html

Comment: You understood it correctly. Thank you I will look into that.

Comment: @itaied Happy to help. Please take some time to mark the answer correct if it works for you, otherwise comment if this isn't your solution so that others can learn.